# Drawable not showing when swiping in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am able to get a background color when swiping using this code:

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable=new ColorDrawable();
                
    colorDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    colorDrawable.setBounds(viewHolder.itemView.getLeft() , viewHolder.itemView.getTop(), viewHolder.itemView.getRight(), 
    viewHolder.itemView.getBottom());
    colorDrawable.draw(c);        
}
```

But I am not able to get an icon while swiping:

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable=new ColorDrawable();
   
    colorDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    colorDrawable.setBounds(viewHolder.itemView.getLeft() , viewHolder.itemView.getTop(), viewHolder.itemView.getRight(), viewHolder.itemView.getBottom());
    colorDrawable.draw(c);

    Drawable bitmapDrawable= ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_edit_24, null);
                
    bitmapDrawable.setBounds(viewHolder.itemView.getLeft()/2, v viewHolder.itemView.getTopp(), viewHolder.itemView.getLeft()/2, viewHolder.itemView.getBottom());
    bitmapDrawable.draw(c);
}
```

What is the issue with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `viewHolder.itemView.getLeft()/2` for both the left and right bound. Therefore it's effective width would be zero.

You're probably looking to use something like:

```
viewHolder.itemView.getLeft() / 2 - desiredDrawableWidth / 2
viewHolder.itemView.getLeft() / 2 + desiredDrawableWidth / 2
```

Comment: `viewHolder.itemView.getLeft() / 2 - desiredDrawableWidth / 2` is for right and `viewHolder.itemView.getLeft() / 2 + desiredDrawableWidth / 2
` is for left?

Comment: No the other way around! The first one is less than the second.

Comment: `bitmapDrawable.setBounds(viewHolder.itemView.getLeft()/2 - 10/2, viewHolder.itemView.getTop(), viewHolder.itemView.getLeft()/2 + 10/2, viewHolder.itemView.getBottom());`, I have written this but still not able to get the icon

Comment: Hmm strange, are you sure the drawable isn't white?

Comment: Ya I am sure, it is purple and will be visible on background

Comment: Ok I got it, `drawableWidth/2` was too small, so I wrote a larger number